# Openshift Tools Eclipse frozen

Tags: java, eclipse, git, openshift, jboss-tools

When creating a new Openshift Application in Eclipse I am able to Login, create a new App on Openshift (it shows up when I access the webinterface) and specify a location where to store the local git repository (I think the ssh stuff works) but when I hit 'Finish' it kinda freezes at the stage 'Cloning ....' (this is the title of the progress bar in the 'New Openshift Application' window) and 'Importing projects into workspace ....' (in the status bar of the main Eclipse window in the background). Anyone can help me? Please tell me what additional information I have to provide, since I'm not familiar with git and Openshift. PS: I'm trying to create a Tomcat 7 Application.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration 2 0 2015-03-24 19:28:16.547
!MESSAGE Exception while setting up logging:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-03-24 19:28:25.245
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Martin'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2015-03-24 21:13:49.348 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.8.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration 2 0 2015-03-24 21:13:54.176
!MESSAGE Exception while setting up logging:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-03-24 21:14:00.226
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Martin'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2015-03-24 21:16:45.270
!MESSAGE Invalid preference category path: org.jboss.tools.common.model.ui.MainPreferencePage (bundle: org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.ui, page: org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.ui.preferences.OpenShiftPreferencePage)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2015-03-24 21:16:45.273
!MESSAGE Invalid preference category path: org.jboss.tools.common.model.ui.MainPreferencePage (bundle: org.jboss.tools.runtime.ui, page: org.jboss.tools.runtime.preferences.RuntimePreferencePage)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2015-03-24 21:16:45.275
!MESSAGE Invalid preference category path: org.jboss.tools.common.model.ui.MainPreferencePage (bundle: org.jboss.tools.usage, page: org.jboss.tools.usage.analytics.preferences.UsageAnalyticsPreferencePage)

!ENTRY org.jboss.tools.common.ui 4 0 2015-03-24 21:19:53.738
!MESSAGE The operation 'Importing project to workspace...' was cancelled
```

Comment: Check if there's any network activity and check the eclipse .log for errors.

Comment: This might sound stupid, but how exactly do I check for network activity? With the Windows Task Manager? I've also never used any log functionality in eclipse?

Comment: Everyone's experience is different. In windows from the task manager you can access the Resource Manager from the Performance tab. The Resource Manager has a Network tab. From there you should be able to figure out which processes are using the network.

In Eclipse there's an Error Log view you can open, but the underlying log file will be in a folder in your workspace: [workspace]\.metadata\.log

Comment: Thanks for your instructions. I followed them and updated my question with the log entries from today. Have no idea where the important part is, though. I don't think it makes a difference if I tried it with a PHP 5.4 application this time, does it? Regarding network activity: at some point when the main window had the status 'Importing projects into...' and the OpenShift window said 'Cloning...' the network activity of the eclipse.exe process decreased continuously and finally disappeared from the resource monitor.

Comment: I would suggest you do do the following. Open command processor. Call '%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jps.exe -v'. It will show all java processes with id's. Then call '%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jstack.exe <put-your-process-id-here>'. Copy whole output and submit the issue into JBoss Tools JIRA here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE.

Comment: try run 'jps -v' and note the process id (pid) for your eclipse instance then run 'jstack <pid>' - it should give a thread dump that could show where it is "stuck".

it could be a ssh key or simple network communication issue.

can you manually git clone the repo from command line without problems ?